# Тип предложения "Любил бы я тебя, Когда б не зной, да пыль... "

Tags: синтаксис

*Ох, лето красное! любил бы я тебя,

Когда б не зной, да пыль, да комары, да мухи.*

(Пушкин).

Какой здесь тип придаточного предложения? Не тип подчинения, а именно **тип самого предложения**.  Неужели номинативное?
Или это и не самостоятельное предложение вовсе? Тогда что?

.===

Добавлю по итогам блиц-обсуждения. 
"Если бы не" - это единый союз.

См., например, тут.
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/274906/%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8

Выделять из него в качестве самостоятельной частицы "бы" и тем более строить на этом основании предположения о сослагательном наклонении в присоединяемой (придаточной) части - это не вариант.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что это **неполное двусоставное предложение с пропущенным сказуемым** (оно выражено глаголом в сослагательном наклонении, о чем говорит  частица БЫ).

Но глагол восстанавливается **не из текста**, как в обычных неполных предложениях, поэтому грамматика **нестандартная** (такие предложения, причем разного вида, иногда называют фрезеологизованными).

Возможные варианты глаголов: когда б не надоедали, не мучили, не беспокоили.

Comment: Знаете, почему я отверг вариант неполного двусоставного? У таких предложений при восстановленном глаголе (даже если это глагол-связка) есть будущее и прошедшее время.  попробуйте-ка образовать его с любым вашим глаголом.  Да вообще, пусть это не строгий и даже субъективный аргумент, но любой глагол (кроме, возможно, опущенного "быть") тут выглядит надуманным и совершенно  ненужным.  Смысл "не комары [которые есть летом]. Ну и при чем тут "надоедали"? Дело не в том, что он не восстанавливается из текста, он вообще никак не восстанавливается в силу отсутствия разумной функции для него.

Comment: Фразеологизированные предложения - это вообще из другой оперы. У фразеологизированных грамматика, как я понимаю, не вызывает вопросов, просто они напоминаю штампы, но имеют при этом некоторую вариативность.    Вот здесь, например. http://studopedia.ru/3_79399_frazeologizirovannie-predlozheniya.html  У нас даже намека нет на какую-то контекстную воспроизводимость. Зато грамматика, наоборот, неочевидная.

Comment: Ох, лето красное! любил бы я тебя, Когда б не надоедали  зной, да пыль, да комары, да мухи.  Глагол в сослагательном наклонении, у него же  нет времени. Но, по-моему, это предложение с нестандартной грамматикой, его условно можно назвать фрезеологизованным.

Comment: А насчет частицы "бы" все объясняется очень просто. "[если] бы не" - без "не" невозможно - или требует еще какого глагола. "Не"  - это и есть глагол при "бы", отрицательная  частица, собственно, сама по себе и восходит к отрицанию глагола "быть"/"есть". Правда это такая седая праиндоевропейская древность, что объяснять на её основании что-то всерьез не получится, но факт остается фактом. "Бы"  при "не" не требует какого-то дополнительного глагола, относясь только к самому "не".

Comment: *"Глагол в сослагательном наклонении"* - какой глагол? Ваш, восстановленный? Нету его там. Сослагательного. Оно только в основном предложении. А подчиненное сослагательности в этой конструкции не требует. не требует. *"Я пошел бы с вами, если Петя не пойдет."*. Ну-ка хоть что подобное, пусть не по смыслу, но по грамматике подобное, с нашим случаем придумайте.

Comment: Кстати, в Нацкорпусе много примеров с такой же грамматикой, например: Я бы в ореховой скорлупке чувствовал себя царём вселенной, когда б не сны Или: .Ведь были б счастливы мы оба,  Когда б не гнусных сплетен рой. И т.д.  Но давайте подождём другие ответы, вопрос ИНТЕРЕСНЫЙ, хотелось бы знать мнение участников.